# Convert GeoPoint to Location

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

I know this is a very noobish question -- but what is the best way to convert a [`GeoPoint`](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint.html) to a [`Location`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) on the Android platform.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
double latitude = geoPoint.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;
double longitude = geoPoint.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6;

location.setLatitude(latitude);
location.setLongitude(longitude);
```

Comment: That sucks that there is no easier way to do it.

Comment: I sure hope that was sarcasm.

Comment: Is this actualy correct as it won´t set the altitude?
—
@hwrdprkns: dividiing by `1E6` will save you even one more character.
—
@stealthcopter: No it not. `Location` is clearly missing a contructor from two floats (`Location` does not even have a default contructor - you need to fill in a useless providor). Actualy, I would habe made `Location` an unmutable like `Date` or `String`.

Comment: +1 This saved me some time figuring how to calculate the coordinates. Thanks!

Comment: BE CAREFUL, there is a nasty bug in the code. At least i think so, correct me if I am wrong. It has to be float latitude = geoPoint.getLatitudeE6()/1000000F (the F is really important, otherwise he floors the value due to the div by INT, which is really far away from the original point)

Comment: +1 @Christian, I was justing looking at latitude of 51.2, and thinking that's not right.