# MonoDroid Convert Location Latitude Longitude Double to Coordinates

Tags: android, xamarin.android

When using a Location Manager to get a Location object containing Latitude and Longitude, the values are returned as Doubles in the form of 1.5......E-314.  How do I convert this to Coordinates like 35.55378, -85.8790?

Comment: This SO post should answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472603/convert-geopoint-to-location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GeoPoint point2= new GeoPoint((int)(21.75 * 1E6),(int)(70.61 * 1E6));
```

this will help you to convert

Comment: Is 1E6 where my Double values go?

Comment: I sure will as soon as I successfully implement. GeoPoint does not appear to be available in MonoDroid.  Is there a reference or using directive I need?

Comment: GeoPoint is from maps addon jar (for people using MapView, etc) Reference can be found here: http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint.html
That said, the principle is still the same, you take the double value multiple by 1E6 and you get the values you are looking for.