# Null pointer exception when transforming Geopoint into Location

Tags: java, android, location

I am having a problem with some Android code. After searching for a way to transform a [GeoPoint](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint) into a [Location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472603/convert-geopoint-to-location) question that seems to give me the answer but when I use the information my program fails with a null pointer exception.

My code:

```
    lat = 52.3725979;
    longt = 4.8998594;
    final GeoPoint geo_1 = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6),(int) (longt * 1E6));

    double latitude = geo_1.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;
    double longitude = geo_1.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6;

    endLoc.setLatitude(latitude);
    endLoc.setLongitude(longitude);
```

Line 171:

```
    endLoc.setLatitude(latitude);
```

Initialization of the endLoc variable:

```
    public class VibroNavActivity extends Activity implements SensorListener{


final static String TAG = "VibroNavActivity";

//location variables
GeoPoint startGeo;
GeoPoint endGeo;
Location loc = null;
Location startLoc;
Location endLoc;
float totalDistance;//the distance between the startpoint end the endpoint
```

The Log:

```
    05-02 12:40:56.789: W/dalvikvm(27983): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a4b1f8)
    05-02 12:40:56.800: E/AndroidRuntime(27983): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    05-02 12:40:56.800: E/AndroidRuntime(27983): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{hcm.haska/hcm.haska.VibroNavActivity}:  java.lang.NullPointerException
    05-02 12:40:56.800: E/AndroidRuntime(27983):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
    05-02 12:40:56.800: E/AndroidRuntime(27983):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
    05-02 12:40:56.800: E/AndroidRuntime(27983):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
    05-02 12:40:56.800: E/AndroidRuntime(27983):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
    05-02 12:40:56.800: E/AndroidRuntime(27983):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    05-02 12:40:56.800: E/AndroidRuntime(27983):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    05-02 12:40:56.800: E/AndroidRuntime(27983):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    05-02 12:40:56.800: E/AndroidRuntime(27983):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    05-02 12:40:56.800: E/AndroidRuntime(27983):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    05-02 12:40:56.800: E/AndroidRuntime(27983):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
    05-02 12:40:56.800: E/AndroidRuntime(27983):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
    05-02 12:40:56.800: E/AndroidRuntime(27983):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    05-02 12:40:56.800: E/AndroidRuntime(27983): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    05-02 12:40:56.800: E/AndroidRuntime(27983):    at hcm.haska.VibroNavActivity.onCreate(VibroNavActivity.java:171)
    05-02 12:40:56.800: E/AndroidRuntime(27983):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
    05-02 12:40:56.800: E/AndroidRuntime(27983):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
    05-02 12:40:56.800: E/AndroidRuntime(27983):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
    05-02 12:40:56.800: E/AndroidRuntime(27983):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: you really need to post all of your code, specifically specifiy what is line 171 of VibronNavActivity.java.  If I had to guess it would be  endLoc.setLatitude(latitude);

Comment: On line 171 endLoc is throwing a NullPointerException, which pretty much says everything. Where are you initializing endLoc, or how ?

Comment: Warning, the solution in the linked post has a bug. You should divide by a float or a double.

Comment: I initialize endLoc as a class variable: see above :)

Comment: @user1321928: no, you didn't you **declared** it as a variable, but never initialized it. Since it's a member variable, it will have the default value, which is `null`. Calling a method on a `null` value (for example `setLatitude`) will result in a NPE.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't initialising `endLoc` you are only declaring it as a variable.

In your constructor, or somewhere lese in a method before line 171 is called, you need `endLoc = new Location();`

Comment: Thank you, the problem was indeed the initialization. The solution: endLoc = new Location("gps");

Answer (score 0):

You have only declared `endLoc`, but the memory won't be allocated at this point. You need to initialize the memory by calling:

```
endLoc = new Location(....)
```

Answer (score 0):

Location constructor needs provider string but i seen somewhere it can be empty string

```
loc = new Location("");
```

Testing it in a moment;