# How to create an action if someone close to some certain location?

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

This might be a noob question for some of you. I want to create an action for android application where if someone is close to some certain location using **geopoint** and i want to verify this using **mylocation** to create an action which will location aware. Any idea ??

Answer (score 2):

You could hold the location you want to reach in a Location object,
and then every time location gets update from the GPS, or every few seconds or so, check ths distance to it. and if it's smaller than a given value, you're there.

check this out
http://advback.com/android/finding-distance-between-two-points-with-google-maps-android/

EDIT:
Since you mentioned you want to use GeoPoint, here's a quick explanation on how to convert between the two:
[Convert GeoPoint to Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472603/convert-geopoint-to-location)