# android-How to find this coordinate on the map

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I've this coordinate : E512113 N310901
it's a place that I need to show on my android map . I could find this place on my gps app but I need to show it on my app too .
this is the code that I've used but it didn't show me that place , I think  google using another type of gps type.

```
    private GoogleMap map;
private final LatLng location =  new LatLng(310901,512113);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    map=((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();


}
public void onclick_btn1(View v){
    CameraUpdate update= CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location);
    map.animateCamera(update);

}
```

Could you help me with a code that could show this location of the map ?

thanks so much

Comment: what kind of coordinates you have !!! it seems you are going wrong somewhere

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472603/convert-geopoint-to-location using this link, convert into lat long and then set it into map.

Comment: which place are you trying to show i mean name of place ???

Comment: the coordinate is right , I checked it on my gps app and it's exactly on the right place . Sorry , I'm new to android and I didn't get you . the link you said , It didn't work for me  . any other idea/

Comment: What is your coordinate system ? You can check this in the settings of your GPS. Probably not WGS84. If you can't find the coordinate system you are using, tell us the name of the place represented by the coordinates you gave in your question ?